# Creating Rasyer object from .adf file using ArcPy gives ERROR 000732

Tags: arcpy, raster, spatial-analyst, error-000732, esri-grid-format

I am trying to use Raster class in Arcpy, to create a raster object from a .adf file

My folder contains all the related .adf files but I am unsure how can I "point" the correct one to create the raster object

for example I tried

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
out_raster = Raster("C:/folder/hdr.adf")
```

But also I tried with w001000.adf and w001001.adf
and the result I get is an error 007032 that my file is not recognised

Comment: I dont know anything about adf-files but have you tried adding the raster to ArcMap to see which file it wants? Or try ListRasters, maybe it will only list valid/recognizable rasters

Comment: .adf extension suggest Esri GRID format. Please try if following works: out_raster = Raster("C:/folder") (assuming that C:/folder contains valid GRID raster set of files